# Obi Wan Kenobi's Appearance

Tags: star-wars

I know there are jokes about how Kenobi looks like Jesus in Episodes II and III but is there a reason he looks like that? Did George Lucas intentionally put some symbolism in his appearance? I looked it up and there were only meme generators and there were no questions like it under the star wars tag.

Comment: ...Kenobi looked like a white british guy with a beard. Jesus was a Middle Eastern Hebrew ;)

Comment: Also, iirc, the Ewan / Jesus memes didn't really come about until around 2015 with his film "Last Days in the Desert" - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3513054/ / http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/994109-star-wars -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

- Too long for comment...
- I doubt you will get the type of answer you are looking for.
- The face is similar depending on what we think Jesus may have looked like.
- Jesus and Obi Wan were both similar and entirely different... from a certain point of view. (hehe)

So I believe your question regards primarily the appearance of the character. If this is the case then you are merely assuming that George Lucas liked the look of the Jesus painting on the wall at his G-ma's house and looked for someone to resemble that in the film. This is ?dangerous? because Jesus did not look like that when he lived and (even if he did) his appearance alone is not really a defining characteristic. Doppelgangers are people too...

You may also be missing the bigger picture if you are asking with regards to not only his face, but his attire as well. Jedi live with little extravagance and since pretty much everyone wears those iconic robes at some point the robes that Obi Wan wears are not unique.

Finally, if your question is more complex than it seems and you are comparing the two men on principle there are key differences to consider. This [link](https://asyourpoetshavesaid.com/obi-wan-kenobi-jesus-christ/) identifies them well in my opinion.

Really the only difference you need to see is that Obi Wan told Luke he needed to kill Darth Vader. Right there the two are completely different, despite any number of similarities or any other differences from their lives. Obviously Jesus would have turned the other cheek and let God sort them out.

There are a lot of religious aspects injected into the Star Wars mythos, but George Lucas himself was not a key follower of any one faith. If I remember right he tended to identify equally with both Buddhism and Christianity primarily, but was still heavy interested in all the different beliefs that exist.

I think that Ewan McGregor looking like Jesus in those films is just another incident of people seeing Jesus in their soup...